# use a string as variable powershell

Tags: string, variables, powershell

```
$VAR_555_SERVER=C:\HERE
$OTHER="555"
$THIS=('$VAR_'+"$OTHER"+"_SERVER")
$THIS
```

Now `$THIS` should be `$VAR_555_SERVER` and `$VAR_555_SERVER` is `C:\HERE`.
Actual result is `$VAR_555_SERVER` as string, how can I use it as variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Invoke-Expression`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx):

```
$THIS=Invoke-Expression ('$VAR_'+"$OTHER"+"_SERVER")
```